# Unable to run nodejs script for a json rpc test case automation

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, json-rpc

I am trying to run a nodejs script written for a json rpc test case automation. However, I keep getting the error:

```
npm run test\resources\nv-jsonrpc-tests\pingServer.spec.js
error missing script: test\resources\nv-jsonrpc-tests\pingServer.spec.js
verbose exit [ 1, true ]/>

var rpc = require('node-json-rpc');

var options = {
// int port of rpc server
port: 8080,
// string domain name or ip of rpc server, default '127.0.0.1'
host: '127.0.0.1',
// string with default path, default '/'
path: 'https://',
// boolean false to turn rpc checks off, default true
strict: true
};

// Create a server object with options
var client = new rpc.Client(options);

client.call(
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "Ping", "params": {classname: 'NServer'}, 
"id": 1},
function (err, res) {
// Check whether it worked and capture the response and error
if (err) { console.log(err); }
else { console.log(res); }
}
);
```

Expectation:

Client send request with 'Ping' and receives 'Pong' from the server response.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to confuse `npm run` and `node`

`npm run` is meant to execute scripts declared in your `package.json` 
`node` can directly execute the script in the file you give

Running this should work

```
node test\resources\nv-jsonrpc-tests\pingServer.spec.js
```